# gitlab image diff not showing because .gitattributes

Tags: gitlab

I want to take advantage of gitlab image diff during merge request. However, instead of the image being rendered or the diff, this is what I'm getting:

[image]

A message saying: `This diff was suppressed by a .gitattributes entry.`
This is the .gitattributes file that we have setup, I don't understand how this is avoiding the image to show properly:

```
* text=auto

*.* text eol=lf

/.idea/* text eol=crlf

*.png binary
*.jpg binary
*.ico binary
*.pdf binary
```

If I remove the entry for PNG, then it is treated as text and the checked out images are not valid. What is the way to flag png as normal image files? What is the default? This seems to work if there is no `.gitattributes` file at all, so what is the proper one?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the `diff` attribute to the `.gitattributes` file.

```
*.png binary diff
```

The behavior is slightly different. The diff is not collapsed by default. But it's ok I think.

Comment: This is very interesting. In any case, it was a bug on gitlab itself, and they have fixed it without any need to change anything from my side.

Comment: After investigating and conversation with GitLab developers: This is a correct behavior of git. [See docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes). When a file is specified as binary, a diff won't be performed until it's explicit declared. ... So this answer is the solution. Regardless of the reasons, this fixes your problem, doesn't? Consider to vote up and mark as solved. :)